# Is it okay to ask and answer a question that may help others?

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answer

A couple of days back someone asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313546/c-sharp-how-do-i-display-this-array-in-a-messagebox-console-application?lq=1) on SO that he wanted to do X (show an array in a message box) in Y (console application) and the first answers it got told the OP that you can infact do X but not in Y but in Z(Forms application) So change your project and all is well. These answers even got upvotes. Then after couple of hours I saw this and posted an answer how the OP can **infact** do what he wants as he wants. Though he did not bother to accept the answer and the thread was thus not closed.

---

I then searched SO and found there was no question/answer that **specifically** asked/answered if we can show a message box in a .net console app. So I thought why not ask and answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326042/show-message-box-in-net-console-application/29326043#29326043) question so it may help others as is the old adage  [share your knowledge Q & A  style](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

- But I received a downvote not only on the question but on the answer
  so it got me thinking that I must have misunderstood the purpose of
  the SO Q & A and thus I post this question here so that in the future if
  faced with a similar situation I know what to do.
  Was I correct in posting the Q & A at all?
- Should I delete my post or let it stay?

Comment: @user4098326 though the link does not exactly answer my query, I have used the guidance given in it to improve my Q & A. thanks